# persistent little error in program to copy and print bits of text (Kochans C book, exercsie 9.4)

Tags: c

am working on a program that take a string of text and extracts a substring from it (Kochan's Programming in C exercise 9.4).  The goal is to create a function called substring that takes as arguments the string, where to start extracting, how many letters to extract, and the result that gets returned

substring (string, number, number, string).

My issue is that while I can punch in a phrase and declare where to begin extraction, the number of digits extracted is consistently incorrect.  I suspect my algorithm is somehow flawed.  The code for my function is below.

```
char substring (char source[], int start, int count,char result[])
{
    int x = 0;

    for (x = 0; result[x] != '\0' || x <= count; ++x){
      result[x] = source[x+start];
}
    return result;
}
```

Another clue is that I get a warning for "return makes integer from a pointer without a cast"

Of course, warnings are not good, but when i print from within the function i get the same error.

The code for the entire program follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

    char source[81];
    char result[81];
    int start, count;
    void readLine(char buffer[]);
    char substring(char source[], int start, int count,char result[]);

    printf ("Please enter line\n");
readLine(source);
    printf ("Please enter where to start extraction (positive integers only     please)\n");
scanf ("%i", &start);
    printf ("And how many characters should the string be?\n");
scanf ("%i", &count);

    substring (source, start, count, result);

    printf ("%s", result);

    return 0;
}


    void readLine (char buffer[])
{
  int i = 0;
  char character;
  i = 0;

  do
{
    character = getchar();
    buffer[i] = character;
    ++i;
}
  while (character != '\n');

    buffer[i-1] = '\0';

}

    char substring (char source[], int start, int count,char result[])
{
  int x = 0;

   for (x = 0; result[x] != '\0' || x <= count; ++x){
    result[x] = source[x+start];

}
  return result;
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To start with, you don't terminate `result` if it's supposed to be a string. To continue, do check the return type of the function again, that error is *very* clear.

Comment: im glad its so clear you dont feel bothered to put the solution.... anyone else?

Comment: Also, you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the function, because you don't initialize the `result` array so its contents will be *indeterminate* and yet in the `substring` loop condition you read the (indeterminate) values of the array. What you should do is to check if `source[x + start]` is `'\0'`

Comment: In the `readline` function you *terminate the string* (by adding the `'\0'` character). Why don't you do it with `result` in `substring`? And you return a *pointer to `char`* in the function, but that's not the function return type.

Comment: Finally, *learn to use a debugger!* A debugger is the most useful tool in your toolbox together with the compiler and the editor. By using a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while watching the values of variables and contents of arrays.

Comment: i figured it was intiialized by declaring its values equal to another initialized string, in this case the source.  The source prints from the function fine.  How would i initialize it without having it loop through and having values assigned other than just typing it out.  To correct the error ive basically been doing trial and error with types and the like, but have not gotten it improved beyond where its at

Comment: You don't need to initialize it at all. Just write to `result` in the `substring` function, *that* is your initialization of the array. (Just don't read from it before that)

Comment: appeciated regarding debugger.  I guess i just got tired of trying random things and stupidly figured someone online would be kind enough to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Five problems in your function: its return type, using `||` on the loop condition, testing `x<=count`, testing for a terminator in the wrong string, and not terminating the target string.

```
char *substring (char *source, int start, int count, char *result)
{
    int x;
    for (x=0; source[x+start], x<count; x++)
        result[x] = source[x+start];
    result [x] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Comment: well thats a fair bit to chew on, ill get cracking thanks.  As im teaching myself it seems clear from this some of my fundamentals are off

Comment: @JerrySingh I would appreciate some upvote or accepted answer credit for my effort? Another small pointer, `source[x+start]` is either `0` (false) and any other value is true. I did not specifically test for a value.

Comment: of course.  lemme work on it a bit.  unfortunately, id been downvoted on the question and have another 6 days to wait to ask another.  god forbid i have another question on this subject problem, and had already doled out my pittance gratitude for an answer.  Seems odd that users would come down off their mountain, downvote, and then not provide much insight to an obviously new user.  Gotta love the interwebs.

Comment: ive reduced it to....                                                              char substring (char source[], int start, int count,char result[])


  {
    int x;
    for (x=0; x<count; x++)
        result[x] = source[x+start];
    result [x] = '\0';



return result;
}

Comment: which seems to work, however i still get an error return makes integer from point.  As inve not gotten to pointers in the text i have no reference for what this error means